# SQL query with function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I have a table of data which i am using a count statement to get the amount of records for the submission date
example

```
AuditId Date    Crew    Shift   Cast    ObservedBy  2ndObserver AuditType   Product
16  2017-06-27  3   Day         B1974, B1975    Glen Mason  NULL    Identification  Billet    
20  2017-06-29  1   Day         9879    Corey Lundy NULL    Identification  Billet
21  2017-06-29  4   Day         T9627, T9625    Joshua Dwyer    NULL    ShippingPad Tee       
22  2017-06-29  4   Day         NULL    Joshua Dwyer    NULL    Identification  Billet    
23  2017-06-29  4   Day         S9874   Joshua Dwyer    NULL    ShippingPad Slab      
24  2017-06-29  4   Day         Bay 40  Joshua Dwyer    NULL    Identification  Billet
```

Basically I am using the following code to get my results

```
SELECT YEAR([Date]) as YEAR, CAST([Date] as nvarchar(25)) AS [Date], COUNT(*) as "Audit Count"
        FROM    AuditResults
        where AuditType = 'Identification' AND Product = 'Billet' 
        group by Date
```

this returns example

```
YEAR  Date  Audit Count
2017    2017-06-27  1
2017    2017-06-29  3
```

Now I want to be able to retrieve all dates even if blank
so I would like the return to be

```
YEAR  Date  Audit Count
2017  2017-06-27    1
2017  2017-06-28    0
2017  2017-06-29    3
```

I have the following function I am trying to use:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetDatesInRange]
(   
    @FromDate datetime,
    @ToDate datetime
)
RETURNS @DateList TABLE (Dt date) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TotalDays int, @DaysCount int


      SET @TotalDays =  DATEDIFF(dd,@FromDate,@ToDate)
      SET @DaysCount = 0


        WHILE @TotalDays >= @DaysCount
        BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @DateList
                SELECT (@ToDate - @DaysCount) AS DAT


                SET @DaysCount = @DaysCount + 1
        END
        RETURN
END
```

How do I use my select statement with this function? or is there a better way?
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetDatesInRange]
(   
    @FromDate datetime,
    @ToDate datetime
)
RETURNS @YourData TABLE ([Year] int, DateText nvarchar(25),[Audit Count] int) 
AS
begin
insert into @YourData
SELECT 
    YEAR(allDates.[Date]) as YEAR, 
    CAST(allDates.[Date] as nvarchar(25)) AS [Date], 
    COUNT(r.Product) as "Audit Count"
from
    (
    SELECT 
        [date]=convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,d.Seq))
    FROM 
        (
        select top 100000 row_number() over(partition by 1 order by A.name) as Seq 
        from syscolumns A, syscolumns B  
        )d 
    )allDates
left join
    AuditResults r on r.[Date]=allDates.[date] and  r.AuditType = 'Identification' AND r.Product = 'Billet' 
where
    allDates.[Date]>=@FromDate and allDates.[Date]<=@ToDate
group by    
    allDates.[Date]

return
end
```

The key is the 'allDates' section ;

```
SELECT 
    [date]=convert(datetime, CONVERT(float,d.Seq))
FROM 
    (
    select top 100000 row_number() over(partition by 1 order by A.name) as Seq 
    from syscolumns A, syscolumns B  
    )d
```

This will return all dates between 1900 and 2173 (in this example). Limit that as you need but a nice option. A ton of different ways to approach this clearly

Comment: i would like to be able to pass in a parameter for the fromdate and the todate

Comment: what was updated?
Incorporating the stored procedure into the function?
How would i call this now?

Comment: select * from [dbo].[fnGetDatesInRange]('2017-05-24','2017-05-30')

Answer (score 0):

you have to create another table `calendar` as (Mysql)- idea is the same on all RDBMS-

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
    `dt` DATE NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `calendar_dt_unique` (`dt`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

and fill with date data.

[more details](http://www.media-division.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/)

Comment: just another approach. Use syntax as your RDBMS.